# I don't have a workstation anymore and I can't do my job - what can I do?

Tags: united-kingdom, employer-relations

My company has built a new premises which is by no means finished, there are contractors working on the building, there's no heating, no toilets and everything is everywhere.  I have no workstation and I cannot do my job.

The 4 weeks before Christmas, I couldn't do my job (I'm a fabricator) instead, I was given jobs to do like packing up machines, painting floors and walls on the old premises (to make good for the landlord) and helping with the move to the new building.

I'm employed in the UK. I am not a contractor. I have worked as a fabricator/welder for the Company for 6 years. The Company has built a new premises but it is not finished. We started moving all the machines and equipment in before the Christmas break. There is no site manager (on site) there are contractors still working on the new building. There are no electrics, some floors have yet to be cemented, there's no heating, sanitation. The building is now jam packed full of machines and equipment but it's all in the wrong place. I can't do my job because I don't have a workstation.

What can I do?

Comment: You need to provide more information – at least the country you are asking about. But beware: "What are my rights?" sounds like a legal question which would be out of scope for this board.

Comment: What kind of contract are you on? Are you getting paid? Have you been told what to do or not to do?

Comment: _What are my rights?_ Where do you live? United States? What state? Are you represented by a union?

Comment: Please note that in many countries just not going to work is a reason to fire you. It might be legal, but the least thing you need to do is notify your employer of that fact. So get a lawyer ASAP. Like TODAY. Or go to work. But don't just sit at home and do nothing, that's a sure way to lose that job for good.

Comment: Yes, this needs more details (type of work, type of contract, country, work circumstances). Also, it needs a clear question - "what are my rights" is obviously off-topic as a legal question.

Comment: Finally, be careful using your real picture here, just in case your boss sees it.

Comment: I'm employed in the UK.  I am not a contractor.  I have worked as a fabricator/welder for the Company for 6 years.  The Company has built a new premises but it is not finished.  We started moving all the machines and equipment in before the Christmas break.  There is no site manager (on site) there are contractors still working on the building.  There are no electrics, some floors have yet to be cemented, there's no heating, sanitation.  The building is now jam packed full of machines and equipment but it's all in the wrong place.  I can't do my job because I don't have a workstation

Comment: Sounds like they want to pay you to help with the move to the new building.

Comment: If that is your real picture I would strongly urge you to change it for your own protection.

Comment: We have spent 4 weeks packing up and helping to move but now we can't do anything because the building isn't finished.  Even if we move the machines and equipment to where they are supposed to be, we can't operate them because there's no electricity.

Comment: @user62335 you may want to edit your post to include the clarifications you put in the comments.  It's likely to be closed otherwise.

Comment: If your workplace has a union, even if you are not a member, you should contact the union health and safety rep. http://www.hse.gov.uk/involvement/hsrepresentatives.htm Express your concerns to them. They have legal protections you don't, and may have information that you don't yet have. If you don't have a union, then speak to your boss yourself or contact the HSE if you have safety concerns. You have a legal duty to raise any safety concerns if you see them.

Comment: @user62335 As far as I am aware, It is illegal in the UK to not provide workers with toilets, a place to either buy or prepare food, and to put them in an unsafe working enviroment without at least the correct training and PPE. It sounds like you would even need a site induction to be on what sounds like an active construction site. Consult with proper legal counsel, and explain to your boss(es) that it is not acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

First things first, get in touch with your boss and ask them to clarify what they expect of you.

Once you have that, contact the HSE and advise them of the hazards/dangers and the circumstances around them

Once you've done that, Citizen's Advice can advise how to handle any legal issues you may face by not going into work and not taking part in the construction project.

Comment: I think the "Talk to your boss" is the only advice needed here unless you actively see problems in the workplace that need H&S attention.  From what you've said, I guess you'll be given general duties to help the changeover, or you take a break until you're needed again.  Either way, your boss will have the answers.

Comment: In the UK, there may be a Union Health and Safety representative, even if you are not a member of the Union yourself. You should contact them before going to the HSE yourself, if possible. http://www.hse.gov.uk/involvement/hsrepresentatives.htm

Answer (score 1):

It seems reasonable to me to have a conversation with your supervisor to see how long it might be before you are able to do your original job once again.

If you are unable to do your normal job due to construction and move related activities and the company is willing to pay you your normal wage to do other things in the meantime, I would just to the work they have available for you at this point in time.

If they have do not work for you to do, are they going to pay you anyway?  If not you need to move on.  If you are stating that you don't believe your original job will be coming back, perhaps its time to move on anyway.